# catch cities when region is selected

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework, select

I have two selects - one for regions and one for cities. What I want is, when I click on `region`, it goes to my DB via Ajax and grabs the right cities. Actually I already grabbed it, but I can't to put it in the `cities` select.

Here is my Ajax function in JS Select function onClick event code:

```
$.ajax({
                url: '/map/index/ajax',

            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                // list of request parameters 
                'r_alias': valueRegionSelect
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $('#city_select').val(data.c_name);
            }
        });
```

console.log(data) show

```
[Object { r_id="39",  r_alias="cu",  c_id="4649", c_name="Kyev" more...}, Object 
,  more...}]
```

exactly what i need.

Ajax Controller:

```
public function ajaxAction() {
        $alias = $this->_getParam('r_alias');
        $result = Map_Model_Map_Factory::getCityByRegionAlias($alias);

        $this->view->cities = $result;
        $this->_helper->json($result);
    }
```

So how can I put it in my select:

```
<select id="city_select" name="city">
                            <?php foreach($this->cities as $city): ?>
                            <option ><?php echo $city['c_name'] ?></option>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the data correctly, it should be

```
var html = "";
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
    html += '<option value="' + data[i].c_id + '">' . data[i].c_name . '</option>';
}
$('#city_select').html(html);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your success callback you could do the following:

```
success: function(data) {
    //data       = $.parseJSON(data);
    var select = $('#city_select').empty();

    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        select.append($('<option></option>')
              .attr('value',item.c_id)
              .text(item.c_name)); 
    });
}
```

Not tested but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create option tags to populate your select

```
$('#city_select').empty();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    $('#city_select').append($('<option>').val(data[i].c_id).html(data[i].c_name));
```